# Does 'key' in object work as a type guard in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why Typescript is complaining about this code.

```
interface PaginationOptions {
    size?: number
    page?: number
}

function test(options?: PaginationOptions) {
    const size = options && 'size' in options ? options.size : 100
    // Typescript complains about `size` and `options.page` possibly undefined.
    const from = options && 'page' in options ? size * (options.page - 1) : 0

    return {
        size,
        from,
    }
}
```

Isn't the `'size' in options` supposed to act like a type guard?

[image]

Comment: "[The `in` operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)". `options.size` and/or `options.page` might still be undefined.

Comment: `'size' in {size: undefined}` -> `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my understanding of the `in` operator was incorrect. `'key' in obj` could be true even in `{ key: undefined }` (as pointed out by @acdcjunior in the comments.

So, I opted to change my code to this to fix it:

```
function test(options?: PaginationOptions) {
    const size = options && typeof options.size === 'number' ? options.size : 100
    const from = options && typeof options.page === 'number' ? size * (options.page - 1) : 0

    return {
        size,
        from,
    }
}
```